# Connecting remote fabric network with client application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm trying to connect client application to fabric-network deployed on remote cloud instance using fabric node SDK. For this, I modified my connection profile with IP address of deployed instance. Everything works fine until submitting transaction takes place. While submitting transaction it is still showing cannot connect to localhost port.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First use

```
discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false } ?
```

then you'll need to map domain names to IP by editing /etc/hosts

```
192.168.1.2 peer0.org1.example.com
192.168.1.3 peer0.org2.example.com
192.168.1.4 ca.org2.example.com
192.168.1.5 ca.org1.example.com
192.168.1.6 orderer.example.com
```

a bit of [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-discovery-fabric-network.html) :

When the fabric network is running in a docker-compose and the node.js application is running outside of the docker containers, it will be necessary to modify the addresses returned from the discovery service. The discovery service sees the addresses of the peers and orderers as host names and ports as they exist in the virtual systems, however the node.js application running outside of docker will only know the endpoints as localhost and port. In the docker-compose file, notice how Docker is mapping the port addresses, these must be same when using service discovery. Using - 7061:7051 will not work as the application does not have visibility into the virtual system and the port address as seen by the peer's discovery service.

Use the asLocalhost with true or false, the default is false.

```
await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, {discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true}});
```

const network = await gateway.getNetork('mychannel');
Notice in the following definition of a peer from a docker-compose file. The port number is the same and has been defined along with the host name peer0.org1.example.com:7051 for the peer and gossip settings. The node.js fabric-client application running outside of of the docker containers will use localhost:7051. There is a mapping of the host name to 'localhost' but there is no mapping of the port address.

Answer (score 0):

On your gateway.connect are you specifying Discovery Options `discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false }` ?

The default for asLocalhost is true and this might be your problem.

Comment: Yeah I already tried this. The error under this case is "cannot connect peer0.org1.example.com.."